# What is wrong with Linked List overloaded put operator? C++

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, linked-list, dynamic-arrays

So I'm having this problem with the put operator of my `LinkedList` code. This ADT is suppose to be both a dynamic array and a Linked List in one ADT with same values. However, when I run the overloaded put operator in main on the object, it prints out the dynamic array but not the Linked List. The operator is on the bottom.

My code for the ADT is listed below:

```
#include "MyArray.h"
#include <iostream>

MyArray::MyArray():size_array(0),size_LinkedList(0),head(NULL),capacity(200){
    try{
        array = new int[capacity];
    } catch(bad_alloc &b) {
        cout << "Constructor Exception: " << b.what();
    }
}

MyArray::~MyArray(){
    size_array = 0;
    size_LinkedList = 0;

    if(array != NULL){
        delete [] array;
    }

    if(head != NULL){
        Node *current = head;
        while(head != NULL){
            head = current->next;
            delete current;
            current = head;
        }
    }
}

MyArray::MyArray(const MyArray& copy) {
    size_array = copy.size_array;
    capacity = copy.capacity;
    if (capacity > 0) {
        array = new int[capacity];
        for(int i = 0; i < size_array; i++){
            array[i] = copy.array[i];
        }
    } else {
        this->array = NULL;
    }

    size_LinkedList = copy.size_LinkedList;
    if(copy.head == NULL) {
        head = NULL;
    } else {
        head = new Node;
        head->value = copy.head->value;
        Node *newPtr = head;
        for(Node *origPtr = copy.head->next; origPtr != NULL; origPtr = origPtr->next) {
            newPtr->next = new Node;
            newPtr->value = origPtr->value;
            newPtr->next = origPtr->next;
        }
        newPtr->next = NULL;
    }

}

MyArray MyArray::operator = (const MyArray& rhs) {
    if (rhs.capacity ==0){
        if(array != NULL){
            delete [] array;
            array = NULL;
        }
        size_array=0;
    } else if (capacity == rhs.capacity) {
        size_array = rhs.size_array;
        for (int i = 0; i < size_array; i++) {
            array[i] = rhs.array[i];
        }
    } else {
        if (array != NULL){
            delete [] array;
        }
        capacity = rhs.capacity;
        size_array = rhs.size_array;
        array = new int[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < size_array; i++) {
            array[i] = rhs.array[i];
        }
    }

    if(rhs.head == NULL){
        if(head != NULL) {
            Node *current = head;
            while(head != NULL){
                head = current->next;
                delete current;
                current = head;
            }
        }
        head = NULL;
        size_LinkedList = 0;
    } else{
        if(head != NULL) {
            Node *current = head;
            while(head != NULL){
                head = current->next;
                delete current;
                current = head;
            }
        }
        head = new Node;
        head->value = rhs.head->value;
        Node *newPtr = head;
        for(Node *origPtr = rhs.head->next; origPtr != NULL; origPtr = origPtr->next) {
            newPtr->next = new Node;
            newPtr->value = origPtr->value;
            newPtr->next = origPtr->next;
        }
        newPtr->next = NULL;
        head = newPtr;
    }

    return *this;
}

void MyArray::push_back(int val){
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = new Node;
        head->value = val;
        head->next=NULL;
        size_LinkedList++;

        if(size_array >= capacity) {
            capacity = capacity + 1;
            int *tmp = new int [capacity];
            for (int i=0; i<size_array; i++)
                tmp[i] = array[i];
            delete [] array;
            size_array++;
            array = tmp;

            int index = size_array-1;
            array[index] = val;
        } else {
            size_array++;
            int index = size_array-1;
            array[index] = val;
        }

    } else {
        Node *newNode = new Node;
        newNode->value = val;
        newNode->next = NULL;
        Node *temp = head;
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
        size_LinkedList++;

        if(size_array >= capacity) {
            capacity = capacity + 1;
            int *tmp = new int [capacity];
            for (int i=0; i<size_array; i++)
                tmp[i] = array[i];
            delete [] array;
            size_array++;
            array = tmp;

            int index = size_array-1;
            array[index] = val;
        } else {
            size_array++;
            int index = size_array-1;
            array[index] = val;
        }
    }
}

void MyArray::pop_back() {
    if(head != NULL) {
        if(head->next == NULL) {
            head = NULL;
        } else {
            Node *pop = head;
            while(pop->next != NULL) {
                pop = pop->next;
            }
            delete pop;
        }
        int *popArr = new int[capacity-1];
        for(int i = 0; i < capacity-1; i++){
            popArr[i] = array[i];
        }
        delete [] array;
        array = popArr;
        capacity--;
        size_array--;
        size_LinkedList--;
    }
}

ostream& operator << (ostream &out, MyArray a){
    MyArray::Node *print = new MyArray::Node;
    print = a.head;
    out << "Linked List: ";
    while(print != NULL) {
        int val = print->value;
        out << val << ", ";
        print = print->next;
    }


    out << endl << "Dynamic Array: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < a.capacity; i++){
        if(i != (a.capacity -1)){
            out << a.array[i] << ", ";
        } else {
            out << a.array[i];
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

Then this is my .h file:

```
#ifndef MyArray_h
#define MyArray_h

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyArray {
private:
    int *array; // dynamic array
    int size_array; // number of elements stored in the dynamic array
    int capacity; // the current number of integer spaces allocated to the dynamic array
    struct Node {
        int value;
        Node *next;
    };
    Node *head; //point to the first node on the linked list
    int size_LinkedList; //number of nodes on the linked list
public:
    MyArray();
    ~MyArray();
    MyArray(const MyArray& copy);
    MyArray operator = (const MyArray& rhs);
    void push_back(int val);
    void pop_back();
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream &out, MyArray a);
};

#endif /* MyArray_h */
```

Then this is my main.cpp file:

```
#include "MyArray.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    MyArray t = MyArray();
    for(int i = 0; i<205; i++){
        t.push_back(i);
    }

    cout << t << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output when I run it:

Linked List: 204,

Dynamic Array: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204

Any help will be greatly apreciated!

Comment: `MyArray` copy constructor creates a linked list with at most two nodes, regardless of how many nodes are in the original. This is combined with the fact that you pass `MyArray` to `operator<<` by value, therefore making a (flawed) copy.

Comment: what do you mean at most two nodes? I can understand that there is something wrong with copy constructor but what specifically is making only two nodes? How can I fix this?

Comment: `newPtr` is set to point to `head`, and never modified afterwards. So the loop keeps assigning to `head->next` and `head->value`. All but two of the newly created `Node` instances are leaked - only `head` and `head->next` survive (and the latter never has its `value` initialized).

Comment: ok i fixed that but it still won't print out all of the LinkedList values. As before, it only prints out the last number pushed to the Linked List while printing everything pushed back to the dynamic array.

Comment: My crystal ball is cloudy lately. The code I can see is still broken; and the code I can't see, I can't comment on.

Comment: `newPtr` is still never assigned to, and still always points to the same node as `head`. So the loop still overwrites `head->value` and `head->next` over and over.

Comment: ok I see my mistake now. The printing is working now. Thanks for helping me. Sorry for annoying you with same problem over and over again. lol